# Why can I get a ftp file by navigation, but not through full path?

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

I an trying to download a file from an ftp server that is in a sub-subfolder. I could find in the expected place with FileZilla but my program (trying to download using the full path) gave an error saying the file could not be found. I set about replicating the precise problem using the ftp command on the linux terminal.

After logging in using username@site and entering a password, I tried this command to download the file, both with and without forward slash:

```
ftp> get Customer/IN/Products.txt
local: Customer/IN/Products.txt remote: Customer/IN/Products.txt
ftp: Can't access `Customer/IN/Products.txt': No such file or directory
ftp> get /Customer/IN/Products.txt
local: /Customer/IN/Products.txt remote: /Customer/IN/Products.txt
ftp: Can't access `/Customer/IN/Products.txt': No such file or directory
```

I then tried navigating to the precise folders and downloading the file from there, copy-pasting folder and file names to avoid misspellings:

```
ftp> cd Customer
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> cd IN
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> get Products.txt
local: Products.txt remote: Products.txt
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||60206|).
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for Products.txt (11411349 bytes).
100% |***********************************| 11143 KiB    6.38 MiB/s    00:00 ETA
```

This download succeeded.

Why are they different, and what can i do to get the first line to work?

Comment: Are you sure that the server uses `/` as its path separator? (FTP is old enough that it doesn't mandate that.)

Comment: Try `lpwd` or `!pwd` to see how the current directory structure looks to the FTP server, then copy that output and use it for the full path. This might not work, if higher levels in the directory tree are not shown. See https://kb.iu.edu/d/aenq

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tried those, I got the response /home/marcus. That is my local home directory, but I don't see what that has to do with the ftp server. I also tried a normal pwd, which gave me /Customer/IN.

Comment: Looks like your FTP server does not support absolute paths.